# Expand list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation

How does one expand this list of rules

`{a->{1,2,3},c->{w},b->{1,3}}`

to

`{a->1,a->2,a->3,c->w,b->1,b->3}`?

Comment: Table[(( % // Keys)[[i]] -> #) & /@ (% // Values)[[i]], {i, 
   1, % // Length}] // Flatten

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rules = {a -> {1, 2, 3}, c -> {w}, b -> {1, 3}};
Flatten[Thread /@ rules]
```

> {a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3, c -> w, b -> 1, b -> 3}

Also:

```
rules /. Rule -> (## & @@ Thread @ Rule @ ## &)
rules /. Rule -> Composition[Thread, Rule] // Flatten
```

> {a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3, c -> w, b -> 1, b -> 3}